# What is good practice in methods of different classes using each other?

Tags: java

Sorry for the question title. I am having a hard time putting this into words. I do not even know how you could call what I am doing. **I appreciate an edit.**
Please have a look at my example.
I like about the first example that it is a simple call in a single line. Also note: BasicJokeGenerator is **only** used by GoodJokeGenerator. Reason for splitting is, classes are both already quite long.
The second example allows you to test `GoodJokeGenerator#generate()` independently from `BasicJokeGenerator` and feels cleaner.

```
class JokePrinter{
    printJoke(){
        System.out.println(GoodJokeGenerator.generate(String topic));
    }
}

class GoodJokeGenerator{
    String generate(String topic){
        String joke = BasicJokeGenerator.generate(topic);
        // ... some logic to make it really good
        return joke;
    }
}
```

OR

```
class JokePrinter{
    printJoke(){
        String basicJoke = BasicJokeGenerator.generate(topic);
        System.out.println(GoodJokeGenerator.generate(String basicJoke));
    }
}

class GoodJokeGenerator{
    String generate(String joke){
        // ... some logic to make it really good
        return joke;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good practice questions are not good for StackOverflow as they can lead to opinions based answers. Post a proper problem that you are facing.

Comment: Question seems very inappropriate. Best to start reading design pattern. Unless you know the different available patterns, you dont know which fits you best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, i would definetly use **interfaces** and **inheritance**, these two are very powerfull tools in OOP (object-oriented programming) and you should know them

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/73BfaRdG)

Comment: more info: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    class JokePrinter{
        printJoke(){
            GoodJokeGenerator joke = new GoodJokeGenerator();
            String newJoke = joke.generate();
            System.out.println(newJoke);
        }
    }

class GoodJokeGenerator extends BasicJokeGenerator{
    String generate(String joke){
        String basicjoke = super.generate(joke);
        // ... add some spice to basic joke 
        String newJoke = basicJoke + addedSomeLogicalSpice;
        return newJoke;
    }
}
```

I would be implementing this way.